# HTML elements overlapping despite block attribute

Tags: html, css

Trying to learn the more advanced features of CSS with positions etc. Using CSS Zen Garden as a guide.

However, I have my heading and navigational bar in a section. With a Div underneath it.

I have put a 2px blue border around the div but for some reason it starts miles up the page underneath the previous section. 
I have a codepen here: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbLwWV

HTML:

```
<body class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="title-section">
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1><img src="header_logo.png" height="61" width="394"></h1>
        </header>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Recruitment</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Concerts &amp; Festivals</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Choir in the Community</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="header-image"></div>
    </section>
</div>
        <div class="intro">
            <p>The Choir</p>
        </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Frutiger,"Frutiger Linotype",Univers,Calibri,"Gill Sans","Gill Sans MT","Myriad Pro",Myriad,"DejaVu Sans Condensed","Liberation Sans","Nimbus Sans L",Tahoma,Geneva,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}
.page-wrapper {
}
.title-section {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #EDF6FF 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    float: left;
    height: 480px;
    width: 100%;
}
header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1040px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
nav {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 30px;
    width: 80%;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A3E0FF;
    border-color: #A3E0FF;
}
.header-image {
    background: url("header_photo.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 303px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
.intro {
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction and explain why, that'll be great!

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Can you state what you want to achieve more clearly?

Comment: your problem is `float: left` in your `.title-section` CSS rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you made your `.title-section` float to the left, and your `.intro` with a relative position. Right now, both overlaps each other, thus the blue border at the top of of the document. And the content of your `.intro` is collapsing after `.title-section`, thus appearing beside it.

In this picture, you can see what happened (red border for `.title-section`, blue border for `.intro`):

[image: What happens now]

If you want them stacked like blocks, in the same layout flow, don't float the title section and remove your `position: relative` on your intro (see [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNERbY) for an illustration).

I recommend you [this article about float](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/) for further understanding.

Comment: Ah such an oversight - that was the result of a previous venture. I must be blind. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You're welcome. I added extra explanation of what happened to your blocks.